# Using JSON extractor to extract values from the response

Tags: json, jmeter, extractor

I have 2 requests. In one request I have used the random text generator and generated some random string and passed that to a variable. After that a new record is created with than random name and unique ID is created. I want to fetch the ID of that record. How do I extract that using JSON extractor.

EG.

Srno  name    id
1     xvyhz   1230-1236(some id)
2     abczz   1230-1236(some id)

I want to get the ID of the 'abczz' which is created by random string generator function and stored in 'variablename' variable.
So how to extract the ID of that generated string using JSON extractor.

Comment: Please format your question so JSON is clearly visible and valid

Comment: {
    "locationApportionments":
    [
        {
            "groupLocationId":null,
       
     
        }
    ],
    "meters":
    [
        {
            "meterId":"8ea69980-5771-4650-af37-37dff115a9d7",
            "meterName":"xyzio",
            
        },
        {
            "meterId":"aa2618ec-00a1-4962-93cf-71b142e9bb4c",
            "meterName":"abcio",

           
        }
],
    "productions":null,

}

Comment: @DmitriT : Above is the json response. In that the meter name is created with the random string function. And the meterid is created once the record is saved. I have saved randomly generated string in one variable 'meterid' So how to extract the meter id with this variable 'meterid'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for `meterId` attribute value where `meterName` is `abcio` the relevant [JSON Path](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) expression will be something like:

```
$..[?(@.meterName == 'abcio')].meterId
```

Demo:

[image: JMeter JSONPath Conditional Select]

More information: [API Testing With JMeter and the JSON Extractor](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/api-testing-with-jmeter-and-the-json-extractor)

Comment: But the meter name is randomly generated and stored in the 'metername' variable name. So while running in batch i will have to take the generated value which is stored in that variable. Can i do like this?
$..[?(@.meterName == '${metername}')].meterId

Comment: When used the variable name it is not extracting the id. I used 
$..[?(@.meterName == '${metername}')].meterId
I have also added the debug sampler to debug the extracted value. But it has not extracted the value. However if i give the static name and debug that with your expression then it is working fine. But when i use the variable name it is not.